# R: Apply function on data frame A dependent on values of data frame B

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames A and B.

```
A = data.frame(x = c(3,-4,2), y=c(-4,7,1), z=c(-5,-1,6))
B = data.frame(x = c(0.5,0.9,0.3), y=c(0.7,0.2,0.1), z=c(0.9,0.8,0.6))
```

If a value in A is negative the corresponding value in B (the same position like in A) should be subtracted from 1. If the value in A is positive the corresponding value in B should not change.

In the end B should look like this

```
    x   y   z
1 0.5 0.3 0.1
2 0.1 0.2 0.2
3 0.3 0.1 0.6
```

Anyone an idea how this problem can be solved?

Thanks in advance,

Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work: `B[A<0] <- 1 - B[A<0]`

```
    x   y   z
1 0.5 0.3 0.1
2 0.1 0.2 0.2
3 0.3 0.1 0.6
```